# Is it possible to set cash contribution status to 'complete' automatically?

Tags: civicontribute

The use case is this: People come with their children to attend a creche facility. To do this they need to be members. They make a cash payment on the spot. Their details are all entered using a Webform that redirects to the contribution page. All good. But the contribution record is always set to Pending as the only way to deal with cash payments on a contribution page is to set the Pay Later option which always sets a Pending status.
So the contribution record always has to be manually edited to change the status to complete even though the transaction was completed on the spot as it were.
Any way around this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to do this with CiviRules: when there is a webform submission of the right type, find the contribution, check it is cash and then change the status to Completed.  You will need the [CiviRules webform Drupal module](https://lab.civicrm.org/partners/civicoop/webform_civirules) in addition to the CiviRules extension.